# Removed firebase now I get Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: swift, linker-errors

Hi I tried to install firebase then decided not to use it so I removed it again from the pods file and the files inside my project, now I get a Linker command failed with exitcode 1 (Use -v to see invocation). I use xCode beta if it important
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSkLX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by going into Xcode -> Preference -> Location and then change Command Line Tools to Xcode 9.0

Answer (score 0):

If a simple clean doesn't work, try cleaning the build folder as well. CMD + Shift + K

If THAT doesn't work either, try deleting derived data by clicking CMD + ,
and then clicking "Locations" tab, and clicking the small arrow the brings you to the location of your derived data folder. Delete the folder related to your project (after exiting XCode). Restart it after deleting and it should hopefully be better.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the red files on the side bar and delete them. Like Pods_Plus_Factum.framework and any others highlighted in red.

Comment: This did not work. In my Product folder I now have my app in red and I can't delete it

Comment: @J-Doe the `.app` file you do not need to delete as it will be created upon compile, but all of the other red files you need to delete (check every folder), this should then fix your issue. This is a linker error because you are linking non-existant files, delete the red to stop linking them.

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure the firebase configuration code is also removed from your app delegate.

Remove all missing files in your project. Missing files are indicated in red text on your files inspector.

Clean your project with cmd + k